# Changing color of the drawing figure with Jbutton

Tags: java, swing

I wrote a program for drawing figures. I am having problem with communication between components. After few hours of different ways I give up.

My program is divided between 2 packages:
First package called panels: App.java, ButtonPanel.java, ColorPanel.java, DrawingPanel.java, MainFrame.java

Second package called shapes: Circle.java, Line.java, Square.java and other figures. There is also abstract class called Shape.java

I want basically press button called btnRed and to be available to draw figure with Red color. In this case I want to draw circle.

[image]

Circle.class

```
package shapes;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import panels.ButtonPanel;


public class Circle extends Shape   {

    private int x1, y1, x2, y2;
    private Color updatedColor;
    private ButtonPanel buttonPanel;

    public Circle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
        this.x1 = x1;
        this.y1 = y1;
        this.x2 = x2;
        this.y2 = y2;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics2D g2) {

        int r = (int)Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x2-x1),2) + Math.pow((y2-y1),2));
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        updatedColor = buttonPanel.getNewColor();

        g2.setColor(updatedColor); 
        g2.drawOval(x1 - r, y1 - r, r*2, r*2);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(int x, int y) {
        x2 = x;
        y2 = y;
    }
}
```

I have all buttons and button listeners in ButtonPanel.java class.

```
package panels;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

import shapes.Circle;

public class ButtonPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    private JButton btnLine;
    private JButton btnCircle;
    private JButton btnTriangle;
    private JButton btnSquare;
    private JButton btnHexagon;
    private JButton btnUndo;
    private JButton btnReset;
    private JButton btnSave;
    private JButton btnLoad;
    private JButton btnPentagon;
    private JButton btnWhite;
    private JButton btnYellow;
    private JButton btnOrange;
    private JButton btnPink;
    private JButton btnRed;
    private JButton btnGreen;
    private JButton btnBlue;
    private JButton btnMagenta;
    private JButton btnCyan;
    private JButton btnLightGrey;
    private JButton btnDarkGrey;
    private JButton btnBlack;
    private Color cl;

    //i want to hook up this with my drawing panel
    private DrawingPanel drawingPanel;
    private Circle circle;


    public ArrayList<JButton> shapeArrayList = new ArrayList<JButton>();

    public ButtonPanel() {

        //instanitiate buttons
        Dimension dim = getPreferredSize();
        btnLine = new JButton("LINE");
        btnCircle = new JButton("CIRCLE");
        btnTriangle = new JButton("TRIANGLE");
        btnSquare = new JButton("SQUARE");

        btnWhite = new JButton("WHITE");
        btnWhite.setBackground(Color.WHITE);


        btnYellow = new JButton("YELLOW");
        btnYellow.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

        btnOrange = new JButton("ORANGE");
        btnOrange.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);

        btnPink = new JButton("PINK");
        btnPink.setBackground(Color.PINK);

        btnRed = new JButton("RED");
        btnRed.setBackground(Color.RED);


        btnGreen = new JButton("GREEN");
        btnGreen.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        btnBlue = new JButton("BLUE");
        btnBlue.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        btnMagenta = new JButton("MAGENTA");
        btnMagenta.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);

        btnCyan = new JButton("CYAN");
        btnCyan.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

        btnLightGrey = new JButton("LIGHT GREY");
        btnLightGrey.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);


        btnDarkGrey = new JButton("GREY");
        btnDarkGrey.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

        btnBlack = new JButton("BLACK");
        btnBlack.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        btnPentagon = new JButton("PENTAGON");
        btnUndo = new JButton("UNDO");
        btnReset = new JButton("RESET");
        btnSave = new JButton("SAVE");
        btnLoad = new JButton("LOAD");

        //set width fot the panel button
        dim.width = 200;
        setPreferredSize(dim);

        Border innerBorder = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Draw buttons");
        Border outerBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(outerBorder, innerBorder));

        //set new Lyaout for ButtonPanel
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gc.gridx = 0; //set position from left to right
        gc.gridy = 0; //set position from up to down
        gc.weightx = 1; //weight controls how irmuch space take relative to the other space
        gc.weighty = 1;

        // tell will it take all the space in the components or not
        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        add(btnLine, gc); //add buttons to the layout

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 1;
        add(btnCircle, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 2;
        add(btnSquare, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 3;
        add(btnTriangle, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 4;
        add(btnSquare, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 5;
        add(btnPentagon, gc);

        //colors///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 6;
        add(btnWhite, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 7;
        add(btnYellow, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 8;
        add(btnOrange, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 9;
        add(btnPink, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 10;
        add(btnRed, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 11;
        add(btnGreen, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 12;
        add(btnBlue, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 13;
        add(btnMagenta, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 14;
        add(btnCyan, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 15;
        add(btnLightGrey, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 16;
        add(btnDarkGrey, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 17;
        add(btnBlack, gc);


        //operations buttons
        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 18;
        add(btnUndo, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 19;
        add(btnReset, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 20;
        add(btnSave, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 21;
        add(btnLoad, gc);

        /*
         * 
         * add action listener to the buttons
         */
        btnLine.addActionListener(this);
        btnCircle.addActionListener(this);
        btnTriangle.addActionListener(this);
        btnSquare.addActionListener(this);
        btnPentagon.addActionListener(this);

        btnWhite.addActionListener(this);
        btnYellow.addActionListener(this);
        btnOrange.addActionListener(this);
        btnPink.addActionListener(this);
        btnRed.addActionListener(this);
        btnGreen.addActionListener(this);
        btnBlue.addActionListener(this);
        btnMagenta.addActionListener(this);
        btnCyan.addActionListener(this);
        btnLightGrey.addActionListener(this);
        btnDarkGrey.addActionListener(this);
        btnBlack.addActionListener(this);

        btnUndo.addActionListener(this);
        btnReset.addActionListener(this);
        btnSave.addActionListener(this);
        btnLoad.addActionListener(this);

    }   //end of constructor    


    //overridden method from actionlistener interface
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        JButton btnFire = (JButton) e.getSource();

        if(btnFire == btnLine) {
            drawingPanel.setCurrentShape(0);
        }   
        else if(btnFire == btnCircle) {
            drawingPanel.setCurrentShape(1);
        }
        else if(btnFire == btnTriangle) {
            drawingPanel.setCurrentShape(2);
        }
        else if(btnFire == btnSquare) {
            drawingPanel.setCurrentShape(3);
        }
        else if(btnFire == btnPentagon) {
            drawingPanel.setCurrentShape(4);
        }

        else if(btnFire == btnUndo) {
            drawingPanel.setCurrentShape(5);
        }
        else if(btnFire == btnReset) {
            drawingPanel.setCurrentShape(6);
        }
        else if(btnFire == btnSave) {
            drawingPanel.setCurrentShape(7);
        }
        else if(btnFire == btnLoad) {
            drawingPanel.setCurrentShape(8);
        }
        else if(btnFire == btnRed) {
            cl = Color.red;
            System.out.println("cl is: " + cl);

        }
    }   //end of actionperformed method

    public void setDrawingPanel(DrawingPanel drawingPanel) {
        this.drawingPanel = drawingPanel;
    }

    public void setButtonPanel(ButtonPanel buttonPanel) {
        this.drawingPanel = drawingPanel;
    }

    public void setNewColor(Color color) {
        this.cl = color;
    }

    public Color getNewColor() {
        return cl;
    }

}
```

When I press red and debugg with System.out.print it says I have that red button storred in cl variable.

```
cl is: java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]
```

However when I pressed Circle button and red button it gives me NullPointerException. It looks like that cl is not passed to the updatedColor variable in the Circle.java class

```
 updatedColor = buttonPanel.getNewColor();
```

It give me null when I sysout that statement. Can anybody help me with that,please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Painting is destructive, each time a paint cycle is triggered, you will need to re-paint the whole state, this means, you will need to store the color of the shape with the shape some how.

Instead of using...

```
updatedColor = buttonPanel.getNewColor();
```

The `Shape` should have it's own color property, which is used every time it is painted.  The problem with your current approach is that EVERY instance of `Circle` will get the same color.

Add a color property to the shape and change the color of the shape when you need to.  Don't forget to call `repaint` on the shape container to update it

```
public class Circle extends Shape   {

    private int x1, y1, x2, y2;
    private Color updatedColor;
    private ButtonPanel buttonPanel;

    public Circle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
        this.x1 = x1;
        this.y1 = y1;
        this.x2 = x2;
        this.y2 = y2;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        updateColor = color;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return updateColor;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics2D g2) {

        int r = (int)Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x2-x1),2) + Math.pow((y2-y1),2));
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g2.setColor(getColor()); 
        g2.drawOval(x1 - r, y1 - r, r*2, r*2);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(int x, int y) {
        x2 = x;
        y2 = y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling

```
updatedColor = buttonPanel.getNewColor();
```

However, the variable `buttonPanel` is a private variable in your Circle class, which you are not initializing.

That's why you have a `NullPointerException`. When you create the circle, you should also pass it a reference to the button panel with which to initialize `buttonPanel`.